# Trying to save data after doing heavy weight migration in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am working on an iOS application that requires heavy weight migration.  What I am doing is converting the attribute type of an Entity in my old Data Model which is of type Integer64, to a type of String in the new Data Model.  Because I am changing the type of the attribute, this requires heavy weight migration.

Now, the conversion is working fine, but unfortunately I am having trouble saving the new Entity after it has been converted, which is why when I launch my application after doing the migration, I'm unable to view the data that was entered using the old Data Model.  Here is the subclass of NSEntityMigrationPolicy that I am using:

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {

    NSManagedObject *newObject;
    NSEntityDescription *sourceInstanceEntity = [sInstance entity];
    NSManagedObjectContext *destMOC = [manager destinationContext];

    //correct entity?  just to be sure
    if ([[sourceInstanceEntity name] isEqualToString:@"MyEntity"]) {
        newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:destMOC];

        //obtain the attributes
        NSDictionary *keyValDict = [sInstance committedValuesForKeys:nil];
        NSDictionary *allAttributes = [[sInstance entity] attributesByName];

        //loop over the attributes
        for (NSString *key in allAttributes) {
            //get key and value
            id value = [sInstance valueForKey:key];
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"myAttribute"]) {
                //here retrieve old value
                NSNumber *oldValue = [keyValDict objectForKey:key];
                //here do conversion as needed
                NSString *newValue = [oldValue stringValue];
                //then store new value
                [newObject setValue:newValue forKey:key];
            }  else {
                //no need to modify the value, Copy it across
                [newObject setValue:value forKey:key];

            }

        }

        [manager associateSourceInstance:sInstance withDestinationInstance:newObject forEntityMapping:mapping];
        [destMOC save:error];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject *)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {

    return YES;
}
```

I've tried to be as thorough as I can, and I've also stepped through the migration process, but unfortunately I can't figure out why the Entity that I'm converting is not being saved in the new Data Model.  I do want to point out something that could possibly be the reason:

This entity that I am converting/migrating has 4 one-to-one relationships with 4 other entities: one relationship has an inverse, and three of these relationships do NOT have an inverse.  I know having a relationship without an inverse is not recommended, but this is how the original Data Model was designed, and unfortunately there is nothing I can do about it.  However, these relationships do NOT change in any way from my old Data Model to the new Data Model.  Does my method:

```
- (BOOL) createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject *)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {

        return YES;
    }
```

have to change now to accommodate this, and thus allowing me to save my data, or can I leave this method alone, and still save the data my simply making changes to the method:

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {...}
```

and still keep the existing relationships as they were intact?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing all of the relationship types to have inverse relationships in the original model, and kept this same structure in the new model.  When I used my above code as is, everything worked fine.

Thanks to all who considered this problem.